# PC magically unlocks BitLocker without USB thumbdrive

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

On premise, we have over 50 PCs with BitLocker Drive Encryption enabled.
For some employees their PC will start (after a complete power off) without using the USB drive.

The USB-drive setting is enabled via GPO, because the machines do not have a TPM-chip onboard. (This is a global setting, applied via the domain controller)

Are there ways to troubleshoot this issue? Rebooting via cmd `shutdown /r /t 0` results in a blue BitLocker screen as expected.

Comment: Is it possible that these PCs have a TPM chip? Otherwise, check the BitLocker encryption policies in gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Operating System Drives.

Comment: *claim that their PC starts*...from what power state? Off? Sleep? Only systems that have been powered down trigger BitLocker's challenge to unlock the boot drive.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question.

Comment: Have you personally verified the required group policy is actually set on the machines used by the users who reported the behavior?